# How do I know which cloud server image to use

Tags: cloud, rackspace

I want to use **Rackspace Cloud Servers**, but am not sure which *Cloud Server image* I should use. Here are the options I have:

- CentOS 5.2
- Gentoo 2008.0
- Debian 5.0 (lenny)
- Fedora 10 (Cambridge)
- CentOS 5.3
- Ubuntu 9.04 (jaunty)
- Arch 2009.02
- Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy)
- Ubuntu 8.10 (intrepid)
- Red Hat EL 5.3  (Choosing this distribution will add an additional usage-based fee of 3¢ per hour)
- Fedora 11 (Leonidas)
  Ubuntu 9.10 (karmic)
  CentOS 5.4

Which one would you recommend me, and why? I'm not familiar with any of these, and I'm a n00b to all of this. All I've ever done is used a managed server.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the best answer would be to choose the one you're most familiar with. As you're not familiar with any of them I can only suggest that none of them would be a wise choice for you at this time for an Internet facing server. You really should do at least some learning off-line first.

Answer (score 2):

I use Rackspace Cloud services now, and you do not only get access to Linux based servers you can also have access to Windows based servers like Server 2003 and 2008. If you are more familier with a windows enviroment you might feel more at home dealing with those.

Here is [a short video](http://chadkeck.com/2009/11/updated-adding-a-site-to-rackspace-cloud-sites/) that describes how to add sites to the Rackspace Cloud.

If you watch the video, you'll see that Rackspace has put a lot of effort into their control panel to make managing their system pretty painless. There is learning curve but not nearly as difficult as learning CPanel on a convential Linux host.

Hope this helps you with your descision.

Comment: That info is actually about Cloud Sites, while the poster is talking about Cloud Servers.  Windows isn't available on Cloud Servers yet, I believe, but it's coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way anyone can answer this question for you based on the info you've provided.  Those are all various Linux distributions with different packaging systems, philosophies, etc., and the best choice will depend on your particular needs.  The only recommendation that I will make is just based on my own experience: I run several Cloud Servers with the Ubuntu LTS (hardy) install, as that is the Long Term Support version, and it's worked out fine for me.

You may want to look into Rackspace's Cloud Sites if they support the things you need, as you won't be managing the server at quite such a low level, considering your inexperience.